# Is it possible to have a close Button inside a DateTimePicker?

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I have used something similar in `Asp.Net`. The Button is used to clear the DateTime.
Can I have the same type of DateTimePicker?

Like this:

[image]

Output of the close Button:

[image]

Comment: Take a look at this: [DateTimePicker Control (Windows Forms)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/datetimepicker-control-windows-forms)

Comment: What this button does? You can add a button with `"X"` caption next to `DateTimePicker` in winforms.

Comment: to clear the date value, i have updated the question @Sinatr

Comment: You could build a UserControl, moving the UpDown (as a stand-alone Control) and the *close/reset* Button to the right of the Calendar dropdown. Then overlay the DTP text section with another Control (a MaskedEdit maybe or a Custom Control) when the *close/reset* Button is pressed. It takes some work. I'm not sure it's worth it.